# Jupyter notebook change theme to dark-cant see output properly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have changed theme to dark in jupyter notebook (linux), and now, i can't see output properly.
Example:
I have matrix

```
matrix = [[0,1,2]
          [3,4,5]
          [6,7,8]]
```

But, when i want to display(write) it, i only see it like this:

```
0,1,2]
3,4,5]
6,7,8]]
```

Like, I am missing the first column
Edit: See picture below
[image]

Comment: Did the matrix variable take this as input without error?.. Bcoz, it should be given like with ',' in between like this: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]].
Whatever you gave will throw a TypeError. Check it out.

Also, feel free to share a screen shot for this problem. That will help more to drill down.

Comment: Yes, I get input correctly, but there is only a problem when I want to print it on screen.

Comment: Try in another browser (e.g. if you normally use Firefox, try with Chrome). This helps pin down where the problem is.